Amplification for digital caliper
I am making a DIY digital caliper, more on the project you can find here.
From various places I found how to design the patterned for the PCBs and with a scope I measured existing calipers to determine what signal are being generated.
Now to calculate the displacement I need to measure a voltage across a capacitor. This voltage looks like this:

My idea is to use to use op-amps to buffer, offset and then amplify this signal. Unfortunately I have never design such circuitry. Can you point me in the right direction, so I can read this signal properly with the STM32F103 ADC?
And also this signal spans from -300mV to +300mV. How come it drops under GND since I don't drive anything lower than GND?

Cheers,
M

Welcome! Please post a schematic.

You can find everything on the git hub repo here : https://github.com/MitkoDyakov/BluePillCaliper/tree/main/Hardware

Please inline it into the question body, not as a link.

Looks a bit like LVDS, but I only see outputs in the schematic. Please clarify what node the oscillogram is taken from.

PB1 (the one with the grammar mistake) is the input to the MCU in question

Ambitious project. +1

Datasheet of U1?

@winny U1 is the PCB interdigitated pattern I believe.

Interesting. Well, if LVDS is pumped in on one end though a passive device, I would expect LVDS-ish output.

U1 is indeed a pattern on the PCB. @winny the pads are not electrically connected, this is why there are not LVDS levels.

Sure, but you “excite” the system with LVDS and sense the output capacitively?

this is correct

I suggest you make a gain-of-one buffer with a CMOS op-amp and look at the waveforms on the commercial caliper and your circuit first. Your 'scope probe will be affecting the signals significantly.
Something like this (use a couple 9V batteries for the power for now):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Keep the sense wire node very short or you'll get all kinds of noise pickup.
The TL081 requires +/- supplies, you could try 9V batteries for testing.

Will do, need a few days to get the parts.

I have created the circuit. I assume the resistor network is there to create an offset. On the non inverting input of the amp I get 1.60V (Vdd is set to 3.2V). I connected two 9V batteries in series. The node where the two batteries connect I tided to the board GND. I measure +9V and -9V on VCC+ and VCC- of the op amp.  The wire that connects the signal and the input of the op amp is just a few mm long. On the scope I don't see my signal, it shows -5V and a flat line.
I will try with another op amp I might have killed the .

I can connect one of the PWM signals to the op amp and I will see the same signal with 1.6V offset right? I want to check my soldering work.

I guess I have zapped the first amp as I don't have any static electricity protection on my workbench. With the new IC get the same signal as before but offset about 2V in the positive direction. You can see the screenshots of the scope here: https://hackaday.io/project/194778-diy-digital-caliper/log/229017-signal-conditioning-part-1 as I cannot put pictures in comments

Unfortunately I don't have any way to access the pads on the commercial caliper. The closes thing I can give you is a readout of the signal from a third party it is in the build log.

any suggestions ?
